# ASP.NET impersonation works only for domain admin

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, active-directory

I have a simple ASP.NET application that uses a SQL Server database. I'm using Windows integrated authentication and asp.net impersonation.

I'm able to login with any user that is member of Domain Admins.

I'm NOT able (and I need!) to login with standard domain user. With standard domain user, I can only view asp.net web pages, that do not interact with SQL Server. When I try to access some page, that has a `SqlDataSource` on it, I get exception:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking intranet and security is not of top importance, then you can set up an authenticated user in an Application Pool, and use the pool in IIS where the page is hosted. This will be the identity that does the work of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it would good to have a service account and this account and grant minimum permission at SQL server.

App pool of yours application should run under this service account.

Refer bellow screen on how to configure the service account at App Pool.

[image]